# howto create a devexpress GanttView like MsProject, with auto layout of dependencies

Tags: windows, devexpress, scheduler, gantt-chart, xaf

I really need help for creating a DevExpress XAF Windows application having a GanttView with special abilities including;

- auto arranging of dependent appointments
- resizing on holidays/not working times
- hiding holidays/not working times, showing only working time intervals

please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will probably get hit with a stick over the head for "me too answer" but I have this task on my list for  near future as I am working on something that needs to offer this functionality.

This is how I was going to approach this: 
1. create BO to hold project definition or a query of some sort. Goo example to follow is how report module BOs  are stored in the database.
2. create win or/and web editor for this type of business object. 
3. the editor will contain either chart form charts module or scheduler view in gantt mode (depending on what you need)

As i get to this task myself I can provide more details or share an example.

here are some links to look at:
`
[[http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q357411]](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q357411%5d)

`

Main consideration for choices you have to make: 
do you just need to display the view or interact with it too (chart control vs scheduler)
do you have to deal with source of the data that already has some schema you have to follow or do you have ability to model data as you want.

Comment: Would not allow me to add more than one link so here are the other two: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djc-HZjPDlY
[http://demos.devexpress.com/xtrachartsdemos/AdvancedViewTypes/GanttSeries.aspx

Comment: thx for the links about gantview and binding datasource to it, but i already know these, I need more functionality in my project because interaction is the key part of it. That's ok, user can move, resize, delete appointments in those videos and links, but ganttview does not provide an auto-layout feature for e.g. moving all-dependent objects together or for holiday intervals like an auto expand-shrink feature. I tried many ways, and finally have a solution with my own classes for timemaps and events, but too complex, like reinventing-the-wheel and does not provide all requirements.

Comment: for your questions, i need interaction & i need to alter an already defined schema so i have to follow it